# Index of every first true value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to return a list of all the first True values and their position.  Here "on" will equal True and "off" equal False

```
t = [False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False,
     True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False,
     False, False, True, True, True, False]
```

Answer should be a list

```
[4, 9, 20]
```

I tried following code:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x]
```

This returns

```
[4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22]
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
ret = []
prev = False
for i, x in enumerate(t):
    if x and not prev:
        ret.append(i)
    prev =  x
print(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = [False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False,
     True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False,
     False, False, True, True, True, False]

indexes = []

counter = 0
for i in range(0, len(t)):
    el = t[i]
    if counter == 0:
        if el:
            indexes.append(i)
            counter = i
    else:
        if (el == True) and (i - counter == 1):
            indexes.append(i)
            counter = i
        else:
            break
print(indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with third party module `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
t = [False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False,
     True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False,
     False, False, True, True, True, False]
s=pd.Series(t)
s = s.loc[s==True][s.shift(+1) != s]
```

Another solution without pandas using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
prev=t[0]
d[prev].append(0)
for idx,element in enumerate(t[1:],1):

    if element!=prev:
        d[element].append(idx)
        prev=element
print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list, {False: [0, 7, 13,23], True: [4, 9, 20]})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an one-liner:

```
on_list = [i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x and not (i and t[i-1])]
print(on_list)
```

However, in this case, there is no reason to use one-liner to make it too complex to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since this answer can help others like me, I copied it from here [enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-first-occurrence-of-true-number/)

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate 
# finding first True value 
# using next() and enumerate()
  
# initializing list 
test_list = [ 0, 0, 5, 6, 0]
  
# printing original list
print ("The original list is : " + str(test_list))
  
# finding first True value
# using next() and enumerate()
res = next((i for i, j in enumerate(test_list) if j), None)
  
# printing result
print ("The values till first True value : " + str(res))
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x and x != t[i-1]]
```

Edit after good comment: (I mean, still it can be a one-liner)

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x and (x != (t[i-1] if i > 0 else False))]
```

Comment: Be careful with this as should the first value be true, `i-1` would equate to -1. Therefore, t[-1] would take the last element of the input list.

Comment: Ah, that's why it tested positive... Thanks!